# How to give a username to clients in a multi-threaded chat client

Tags: java, networking, arraylist, chat

**My Problem:** Currently, I do not understand how to assign each Client a username for my chat client. Therefore, I just have the output as: "A user says: [user's chat]"

**My Code:**

Client.java (Self Explanatory)

```
package chatroom;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client("localhost", 9090);
    }

    private Socket clientConnection;
    private PrintWriter sender;
    private BufferedReader receiver;
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String request;
    public static boolean firstMessage = true;

    public Client(String serverip, int port) {

        try {
            clientConnection = new Socket(serverip, port);
            sender = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream(), true);
            receiver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientConnection.getInputStream()));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Thread(new ChatHandler(clientConnection)).start();

        while (true) {
            if (request != null) {
                
            } else {
                System.out.println("Welcome to the ChatRoom! Type to get started!");
            }
                request = scan.nextLine();
                sender.println(request);
            if (request.equals("quit")) {
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Server.java (Self Explanatory)

```
package chatroom;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(9090);
    }

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientConnection;
    private ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients = new ArrayList<ClientHandler>();

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("[SERVER] Waiting for Client Connection...");
            try {
                clientConnection = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("[SERVER] Client Connected Successfully!");
            ClientHandler clientThread = new ClientHandler(clientConnection, clients);
            clients.add(clientThread);
            Thread t = new Thread(clientThread);
            t.start();
        }
        
    }
}
```

ClientHandler.java (Runnable that receieves input from user and sends it back to clients)

```
package chatroom;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientConnection;
    private BufferedReader receiver;
    private PrintWriter sender;
    private String clientRequest, clientUsername;
    private ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientConnection, ArrayList<ClientHandler> clients) {
        this.clientConnection = clientConnection;
        this.clients = clients;

        try {
            receiver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientConnection.getInputStream()));
            sender = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String userInput = receiver.readLine();
                if (userInput.equals("quit")) {
                    System.out.println("[SERVER] Received Forced User Shutdown Input. Now Exiting...");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("[SERVER] Received User Input... ");

                sender = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.out.println("[SERVER] Attempting to Send the Message to the Other Clients...");

                for (ClientHandler aClient : clients) {

                    String serverResponse = "A user says: " + userInput;
                    aClient.sender.println(serverResponse);

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        

    }

}
```

ChatHandler.java (Runnable that outputs the chat to the client which allows the client to type while output is being produced)

```
package chatroom;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ChatHandler implements Runnable{

    private Socket clientConnection;
    private BufferedReader receiver;
    
    public ChatHandler(Socket clientConnection) {
        this.clientConnection = clientConnection;
        try {
            receiver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientConnection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                String serverResponse = receiver.readLine();
                
                
                if(serverResponse == null) {
                    break;
                }
                
                System.out.println("\n" + serverResponse);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    
    
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you all so much!
~AbysssCoder

Comment: Most servers require that you log in.  This sets the user name.  In `ClientHandler`, I would expect a "login" command that sets the username.  Without that, I would prevent any other command (such as chat or joining a room) except for "quit".

Comment: @markspace So should the ClientHandler send a username request to each client, and then I just store that as a username string in the Client handler? I'm not familiar with login systems.

Answer (score 1):

A way that you can send the text and username is creating a new Object

It can be something like this:

```
public class Message() implements Serializable {
     public String message_, username;
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     public Message(String message, String Username){
         this.message_ = message;
         this.username = Username
     }
}
```

Then instead of using the normal DataInputStream you use ObjectInputStream to send the object.
like this

```
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStram(socket.getInputStream);
  ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputSream(in);

  Message message = (Message) input.readObject;
  System.out.println("From: " + message.username + ": " + message.message_)
```

And you also have to use ObjectOutputStream y recomend you to investigate about sending objects trhough sockets